# Accessing Cloud Pub/Sub Message attributes in Cloud DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

According to what I read of DataFlow, the Pub/Sub datasource only gives the message body to work with in the pipeline. We have a use-case where we want to inspect the attributes of the message to make certain decisions. Is there any way of achieving this currently? I'm open to extending the Pub/Sub I/O to incorporate this if required.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no way to access the message attributes of your messages via the `PubsubIO` connector, but it would clearly be useful to do so. This is tracked in Apache Beam (incubating) as the issue [BEAM-404](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-404).

I recommend following this issue to keep abreast of new developments.

Comment: Is accessing the message attributes of a messages via the `PubsubIO` still not supported?

Comment: It is now tracked explicitly as [BEAM-404](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-404). I will update my answer.